# How to call connection:didReceiveData

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

Right now I am making a POST in my iOS app, and in the POST I have this

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; // Edited
```

So that `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {` will be called with it is finished, but not using the connection gives a warning, and I know this is not the correct way to have it be called, so how can I declare a connection so that `didRecieveRespose` and `didReceiveData` are called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare like this:-

```
(void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

or

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: U can write like this
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
or
(void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];